# Sharedpreferences values not updated

Tags: flutter

I have a Screen A that loads data from sharedPreferences instance.

There is a button to open Screen B:

```
onTap: () {
       print("Card1 Clicked");
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => MisClinicas()));
```

Then on Screen B I am changing some sharedPreferences values and then I go back to Screen A clicking on the back button at AppBar.

Mi issue is than the new sharedPreferences values are not updated in Screen A to the new values updated in Screen B.

What should I do to get the sharedPreferences updated values when going back from Screen B to Screen A?

EDIT SCREEN B

This are the methods executed in Screen B to change sharedPreferences:

```
Future<String> setClinicaIdUsuarioActual(String clinicaId,) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString('clinica_id', clinicaId);

  ;

    setState(() {});
  }
  Future<String> setClinicaUsuarioActual(String clinica) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('clinica', clinica);
    miClinica = prefs.getString("clinica");
   

    setState(() {});
  }
```

EDIT SCREEN A

```
@override
  void initState()  {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
      print("estoy en initstate de home");
      getEmailUsuarioActual();
      getImagenUsuarioActual();
      getIdUsuarioActual();
      getClinicaUsuarioActual();
      getClinicaIdUsuarioActual();


  }


 Future<String> getEmailUsuarioActual() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    miEmail = prefs.getString("email");
print("*****EMEIL "+miEmail);
    _datosLeidos = true;

    setState(() {
    });
  }
  Future<String> getImagenUsuarioActual() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    miImagen = prefs.getString("foto");
    print("*****IMAGEN "+miImagen);

    setState(() {
    });
  }

  Future<String> getIdUsuarioActual() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    miId = prefs.getString("id");
    print("*****Id "+miId);

    setState(() {
    });
  }
  Future<String> getClinicaUsuarioActual() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    miClinica = prefs.getString("clinica") ?? "No has seleccionado ninguna clínica" ;
    print("*****Clinica "+miClinica);

    setState(() {
    });
  }

  Future<String> getClinicaIdUsuarioActual() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    miClinicaId = prefs.getString("clinica_id");
    print("*****ClinicaId "+miClinicaId);

    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you share code where you change SharedPreferences?

Comment: @Tuqay, yes sure. I update my question.

Comment: @Tuqay, done, you both methods already in my question as EDIT

Comment: when you go back to Screen A, do you call `getString` again?

Comment: @Tuqay, yes, at Screen A there are some methods to get sharedpreferences values, at initstate.

Comment: Can you please provide them too?

Comment: There is one thing I want to mention is set methods of sharedPreferences are asynchronous, you should call them with `await`keyword. But I don't think it will solve your issue. Add `await` before `setString` and if it doesnt work, reply here

Comment: @Tuqay, all methods published

Comment: @Tuqay, the sharedpreferences values are updated correctly in screen B, but not refreshed on Screen A when back from B to A. If I restart the app, then screen A shows the updated sharedpreferences values

Comment: @Tuqay, I guess it is a matter of lifecycle from screens, then initstate at screen A is only executed the first time it is opened, not when back to A from B

Comment: You have the answer then

Comment: @Tuqay, I think so, but I am not sure if I am able to get it working, I guess I have to use WidgetsBindingObserver  at screen A, do you agree?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not expert at that topic. Go ahead and ask another question

Comment: You can use state management to share data between screens. Use providers or blocs, and you can achieve this pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some state management to improve sharing data between screen.

For example, if you use Provider here to provide the value for screen A & B, when you update the data on either screen, both widget can be notified about the changes. It is good if you have multiple screens which is sharing the same data.

Learn more about state management in flutter here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple